# Cursor shadow for custom cursors

Tags: wpf, windows, mouse-cursor

I have edited the default Aero Arrow mouse cursor from Windows 7, added a little icon to it and saved it as new .cur file. The cursor editor is RealWorld Cursor Editor 2013.1 which seems to be good at that. The new cursor works fine when I select it as part of my Windows cursor theme. It also has a shadow like the default cursor or any other.

But when I use this cursor in my application as a custom cursor, it has no shadow. The alpha blending is displayed correctly (the Aero arrow cursor has slightly anti-aliased edges, not like the old Win2k cursor that had pixel-sharp edges). Just the system-generated shadow is missing. You know, the shadow that can be enabled in the user's mouse pointer settings.

What do I need to do to make Windows draw the default shadow under my custom cursor?

Using .NET 4.0 WPF on Windows 7, if it matters.